# Replace <br> with <br />

Tags: javascript, markup, w3c-validation

I'm looking for a script to replace

```
<br>
```

with

```
<br />
```

Also looking to change

```
border=0
```

into

```
border="0"
```

Is this possible to do so that I could pass w3c compliance? Thanks in advance - Dave

Comment: It'd be simpler to change your DOCTYPE to "html" :-)

Comment: I hope you're not looking for a javascript script to do that. That would be silly.

Comment: A script? Are you planning to run this on the browser? The sources (or the HTML generation) needs to be fixed...

Comment: Are you wanting use JS to fix your code client-side?  There's not much point, the horse has left the barn at that point.

Comment: I guess you would do the replace in multiple files? most text editors will allow you to open up a project folder and do a project wide find&replace

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question no, it won't. It's not that javascript isn't capable of replacing and/or fixing malformed tags but by the time your script runs the html has already been parsed.

Comment: Or your script never runs at all.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you looking for
but for that kind of changes I use find and replace in the HTML files if you can have access to them. Don't forget to chose the option to replace in all files open or in the solution.

Your changes are not enough complicated to use a regular expression.
And it would be a bad idea to run a javascript script every time instead of fixing it once.